# NodeJS Sticky Session for Users sharing same IP Address

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, node-cluster, sticky-session

Our `NodeJS` (With Sockets and HTTP) project is being used by users (all are working from same office, same network) sharing a same public IP Address. I have put a sticky session implementation which generates an hash based on Public IP Address of the user, then allocates a node worker for it. This stickiness is required for `socket.io` to work. Since all users are sharing the same public IP Address, hash is always same and hence makes use of only one worker. All the other workers are not being used :-(

Since I am using a very low level NodeJS's `net.createServer` API with `pauseOnConnect` option, I am not able to get any other information like headers, cookies to create unique hash for each user.

Questions:

- Is this stickiness really required ? I am using `socket.io-redis` to broadcast messages. Not sure if this adapter will help me in handling socket connections and explicitly stickiness need not to be managed. I tried this but doesn't seems to be working.
- Is it possible to read headers/cookies from a connection object emitted by `net.createServer` ? I think it is not possible as it doesn't have any implementation of HTTP at this level.
- Is it possible to make use of `http.createServer` API and pass request object to worker from the master process. This way I can read headers/cookies and generate a unique hash.
- Worst case, is it possible to override client's IP Address at the proxy level(using `nginx`) and set some dummuy unique IP Address for each user.

Comment: Stickiness isn't required for socket.io. Try using without it. it should work.

Comment: @tbking `socket.io` requires stickiness. https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/ Also tried locally, and it does throw error saying 'Invalid Session' when subsequent request go to different nodes. Created an issue as well here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3044